# TOTP defaults and extensibility

Tags: standards, one-time-password

Recently, I was implementing 2FA using TOTP according to RFC 6238. What caught my attention were the default values: 30s time step, epoch as the start time of counting, and especially the widely used parameters (not directly recommended by the RFC): secret represented in Base32, codes of lengths 6 and HMAC-SHA1 as the underlying algorithm. My questions:

1. Is it reasonable to assume changes in widely used implementations, using the parameters above? This implies implementing a way to customize the parameters instead of hard coding the default values.
2. Are there any known plans to "upgrade" the used parameters by widely used client implementations, e.g. Authy, 1Password, Google Authenticator etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Answer on the first question depends on your needs. If you have implemented 2FA on your server and looking for some app to generate codes on a client side - you just need to choose an app which already supports working with different parameters, so in this way you can be sure that next app update won't broke your auth system.

As for the common realization: most of the auth servers use 6-digits codes using 32-symbols seeds in Base32 and SHA1 as a hashing function, but I've met some systems with SHA-256 and 52-symbols seeds.